# is there any way to call multiple datas in jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports

I wanna ask about how to display the data below the previous data because when i tried to display the data, the next data that i have displayed in the next page, the thing that i want is i want to display the items below from the previous one.

for example of the table and the data are

table name : Tax

```
Tax code           tax name                   tax amount
1                  regresive tax              2000.00
2                  capital gain tax          3000.00
3                  property tax               5000.00
```

the query is

```
select tax.name,tax.amount
from table tax
```

and the output is:

```
page 1

regresive tax        2000.00

page 2

capital gain tax     3000.00

page 3

property tax           5000.00
```

the output I want is:

```
page 1
regresive tax        2000.00
capital gain tax    3000.00
property tax         5000.00
```

Comment: Neither Postgres, nor the default command line client `psql` will show "Page 1" or "Page 2" - which tool do you use that produces the "page 1", page 2" output?

Comment: PostgreSQL has no concept of display pages. You should specify which tool you are using in order to query the DB.

Comment: oops sorry everyone what i forgot to tell you guys that i used jasper report for making the view and the pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Text Fields for displaying data, make sure you're placing them in the Detail band.

Also make sure you don't have much whitespace below the text fields - so, for example, if the height of the text field is 30px, the height of the detail band should also be about that much (if there are no other elements there).